# Deleting photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have synced my photos from my iPhone to my Mac but now I want to remove the photos from my phone. How do I do this? It won't let me delete the "events" or some of the "albums".

Answer (score 2):

Tap on the Share button, then select the photos you want to delete by tapping on them and then tap Delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iPhoto to copy the photos from your iPhone to your Mac, iPhoto will ask you of you'd like to delete the pictures from the iPhone after the sync. This can be a good way of clearing off a large number of pictured easily.

Also, the Image Capture app delivered with OS X will let you select all photos and then delete them with one click and then an OK in a confirmation dialog.

Comment: What do you mean by `Image Capture app` ? Do you mean `Photos?` ?

Comment: @gideon There's an app named "Image Capture".

Comment: Yep. This helped a LOT!